# When limit in distribution exists.

Tags: probability-theory

Consider $X_{1} \dots X_{n}$ are independent random variables with exponential distribution with parameter $k$. 
Now let $Z = n^{-1} \sum X_{i}$

So we want to know for what values of $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ limit in distribution exists : $\sqrt{n}(Z \sin{Z} - c_{1}) \to \operatorname{N}(0,c_{2})$

Actually I thought about consider characteristic function. But $\sin$ factor is awful. Maybe there is other tricks?

Comment: Use the "delta method" described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method .